# How to write a non generic type for the constructor of a generic class in typescript or use generic with utility types?

Tags: typescript

I have a registry of class constructors. The registry is also used to create instances of these classes. To allow creating a registry of anything that extends `Base`, I use a generic class `Registry` that infers its repositories from the descriptors passed in constructor. It works well.

But each instance generated with a registry should also reference it and I'm stuck at getting TS to keep a precise inference.

```js
type RepositoryDescriptor = {
    ctor: () => (new(options: RepositoryOptions<any, any>) => Base<any, any>)
    // would like to have something like a generic class constructor to allow inference
    // ctor: () => (new(options: RepositoryOptions<R, any>) => Base<R, any>)
}

type RepositoryCtor<T extends RepositoryDescriptor> = ReturnType<T['ctor']>
type Repository<T extends RepositoryDescriptor> = InstanceType<RepositoryCtor<T>>
// Think of this logic either that doesn't work
// type Repository<T extends RepositoryDescriptor, R> = (InstanceType<RepositoryCtor<T>>)<R>

type RepositoryOptions<R, V> = {
    n: string,
    v: V
    r:  R
}

class Registry<R extends {[key: string]: RepositoryDescriptor}> {
    repositories: R

    constructor(registry: R) {
        this.repositories = registry
    }

    get<K extends string & keyof R, T extends Repository<R[K]>>(key: K, v: T['v']) : T {
        let ctor = this.repositories[key].ctor();

        return new ctor({r: this, v, n: key}) as T
        // Alternatively of working on constructor, something like this may be great
        // return new ctor({r: this, v, n: key}) as T<R>
    }
}

class Base<R, V> {
    registry: R
    n: string
    v: V

    constructor({n, v, r}: RepositoryOptions<R, V>) {
        this.registry = r
        this.n = n
        this.v = v
    }
}

class A<R> extends Base<R, boolean> {}
class B<R> extends Base<R, number> {}

const registry = new Registry({
    A: {
        ctor: () => A
    },
    B: {
        ctor: () => B
    }
})

let a = registry.get('A', true) // It's typed as A<any>, registry type information is lost
let b = registry.get('B', 50) as B<typeof registry> // Cast can solved my issue but I prefer to avoid it if possible

let c = a.registry.get('C', true) // Should be an error
let d = b.registry.get('C', true) // Error is raised as b is casted
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYHsDOBLYCBOIAiEkGMMUx0MoBeKAbwCgp6p9SAuKACgEoKA+dgOwgB3NghIoEfJKziJUpEAHkxEpAB4AhnxAAaKJpDcu5XgCF1SCBq279hugwD0DqIIQBXADYATKB5QBraHQoAAt1ADdoJAQAWwhgEJQ+AHNfAOh1KGSIASJ8Rg9zJEYVYAw3JkwoYPUPDwRBKCSAMwgMHPwIe3onRhZ2I142AWFRYHFJaXhkNExFZUlVGBstQx4oMwsllYMOGgBfGhpQSFhpuTmAYVJVABUoCAAPYByvYpkZ+VwCIhJMXkocGAbgwfFu4EstwA2gBySoYGEAXW4xwhZ1ksywdwez1e73OmJweEIxFIAKgAElJMBNJ1wZAlgT5NdMHduCjerdEnx-FAEM1qolivVkih8hA0CE2oL1MAoF4EHg+DC5a4MP4aL0TtAPhcsfcni8+G90Z85t8SX8MLoYOS2FSkDS+HSIYyMcybrd2RwlijUaddYSlOMVNsoAA1cm0BhQPisR1EFLabpQcKscMpjCsWAHI74QpIfGihMgJY4o0mqhQwIgeNlJLJRFTd3m4m-Uj7XjRhjtFtEPDSI4x-ClcrwtjtYtlWuwLjdmP0BIoJAAOl7Zv7xUok+X05ThxT2WAqgA0uW8VAEw2oAAyKA1-mwXQG3HG-F90swKEn5HcNg11gT10NMoGhGFwiRLhWHuecFw8eI+iqSgl1Xdc9RQPBqwgEBERXccOAAbiHBd6HaYFQVjIREIwNgqCzQVl2A3Q43vbD9i4cxQJTGNegAQQ8F5QVlFBIg8EA+QFNV-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)

As I feel it, there's two thinkable ways :

1. Working on `RepositoryDescriptor` type to make it works like a generic class constructor that allow inference of registry type
2. Working on `Repository` type be able to use it with a generic and cast as `Repository<R>` in `Registry::get`

I've failed on both approaches.

I'm not closed to another pattern to achieve the same goal if more convenient with typescript.

Comment: There are multiple errors in the playground but you don't seem to be asking about any of those. Please [edit] your example to resolve them so that they aren't a distraction.

Comment: @jcalz My bad. It was a try to solve issues by making RepositoryDescriptor constructor generic as well. There's no more errors now

Comment: So, as you say, you have two problems. Could you [edit] so that you're only [asking about one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/511366)? Otherwise it risks being closed with "Needs more focus: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only."

Comment: @jcalz As I wrote in my question, I'm pretty sure the two issues are closely related and caused by my inability to type correctly the callbacks that are provided to registry constructor. The title of the question came from this idea. I've edited a bit the question to hopefully make it more obvious.

Comment: They aren't particularly closely related as far as I can tell. One is that you didn't put `Base` in your return type of `ctor`, and the other is that TypeScript lacks higher kinded types. Please choose one of those to focus on. Nothing stops you from opening a second question for the other one once the first one is resolved, or resolving one yourself (it seems like `=> Base<any, any>` instead of `=> any` would fix it the first one quickly) and then having this focus on the other one.  I'll re-engage if that ends up happening here.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks a lot for your time. I've messed up with this obvious return value through my experiments. I've narrow down to what is the heart of my demand.

Comment: In order to represent what you're doing easily, TypeScript would need *higher kinded types* as described in [ms/TS#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213).  It doesn't, so you'd need to work around it. There are various approaches but I don't find any of them particularly user-friendly.  If you're willing to add a member to a "class list" for each subclass of `Base`, you can do it [as shown in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wE26yN). Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Damnit ! A 2014 thread still opened XO Your workaround with declaration merging is really nice as it avoids to cast each instance (there's also nice learnings for me on a lot of details when I read your playground). In real case, the first ClassList interface will be declared in a library module alongside Registry and Base. Each subclasses will live in their own file. Ideally, merging should follow the same logic. Can you also have a word about how to correctly handle this in your answer ? Thanks !

Comment: I don't know what to say about multi-file solutions here, you could probably do [module augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation), but it's not super easy for me to test this in my environment and is essentially out of scope for the question as asked.  I hope it's okay if I can just write up my answer as-is and if you can't figure out how to do augmentation you open a new question for it.

Comment: That's totally fine. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor aside to start with. It will be much easier to make `RepositoryDescriptor` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the construtor's return type `T`:

```
type RepositoryDescriptor<T extends Base<any, any>> = {
    ctor: () => (new (options: RepositoryOptions<any, any>) => T)
}
```

and then you can write `Registry` in terms of the type arguments to `RepositoryDescriptor` in its set of `repositories`. That way you don't have to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to recover them later:

```
class Registry<R extends { [key: string]: Base<any, any> }> {
    repositories: { [K in keyof R]: RepositoryDescriptor<R[K]> }

    constructor(registry: { [K in keyof R]: RepositoryDescriptor<R[K]> }) {
        this.repositories = registry
    }

    get<K extends string & keyof R>(key: K, v: R[K]['v']) { // return type?
        let ctor = this.repositories[key].ctor();
        return new ctor({ r: this, v, n: key });
    }
}
```

So we use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to convert from `R` into the type of `repositories`, and then you don't need to undo it later. Just write `R[K]` instead of `Repository<R[K]>`.

This isn't necessary, but it's easier to handle.

---

The main problem you're having is trying to apply a new type argument to an *arbitrary* generic class.  But TypeScript doesn't let you abstract over generic types this way.  You can only abstract over regular data types, the lowest [kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kind_(type_theory)) of type:

```
// you can do this
type Foo<T extends unknown> = ⋯T⋯ 
type Bar = Foo<string>;
```

You can't bump that up one level and talk about *generics*, like

```
// you can't do this
type Baz<F extends UnknownGeneric> = ⋯F<string>⋯
type Qux = Baz<Foo>
```

You can't say that `F` is "generic" and then write `F<string>` inside the body of `Baz`. And you can't pass `Foo` to `Baz` because `Foo` isn't really a first-class thing by itself. You can write `Foo<string>` but not just `Foo`.

That would require *higher kinded types*, as requested in the longstanding open GitHub issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213.

So there's no direct way to say

```
class Registry<R extends { [key: string]: UnknownGeneric & Base<any, any> }> {
    //             that's not a thing ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    repositories: { [K in keyof R]: RepositoryDescriptor<R[K]> }

    constructor(registry: { [K in keyof R]: RepositoryDescriptor<R[K]> }) {
        this.repositories = registry
    }

    get<K extends string & keyof R>(key: K, v: R[K]['v']): R[K]<this> {
    // that's not a thing -------------------------------------^^^^^^
        let ctor = this.repositories[key].ctor();
        return new ctor({ r: this, v, n: key });
    }
}
```

because there's no way to say that `R[K]` will be "generic".  But if we could, the idea is that `R[K]` would be a generic subtype of `Base` which takes a single type argument for the `Registry<?>`, and we'd use [the polymorphic `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) to represent that we're putting `this` in for `r`.

---

There are various workarounds and approaches to let you express higher kinded types in TypeScript.  One version I've seen is to compile a list of generic types you want to be able to apply type arguments to, keeping them in an interface so you can [merge](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) new members in when you want.

Here's how it could look with this example:

```
// list of generic subclasses of Base, initially empty
interface ClassList<R extends Registry<any>> { }

// produce the equivalent of T<R> if T were a higher kinded type
type Apply<T, R extends Registry<any>> =
    { [K in keyof ClassList<R>]:
        T extends ClassList<any>[K] ? ClassList<R>[K] : never
    }[keyof ClassList<R>]

class Registry<R extends { [key: string]: Base<any, any> }> {
    // ⋮    
    get<K extends string & keyof R>(key: K, v: R[K]['v']): Apply<R[K], this> {
        let ctor = this.repositories[key].ctor();
        return new ctor({ r: this, v, n: key }) as Base<any, any> as Apply<R[K], this>;
    }
}
```

So, if this works, then `Apply<R[K], this>` will be equivalent to the intended `R[K]<this>`.  Except that `R[K]` will be some specific subtype of `Base<any, any>` and it won't be generic, so it'll be more like "replace the type argument in `R[K]` with `this`" instead of "pass into generic `R[K]` the type argument `this`".

---

Let's test it out:

```
class A<R> extends Base<R, boolean> { a = 1 }
interface ClassList<R> { A: A<R> } // <-- merged in

class B<R> extends Base<R, number> { b = 2 }
interface ClassList<R> { B: B<R> } // <-- merged in
```

So `ClassList<R>` contains two members, one of type `A<R>` and one of type `B<R>`.  And now when we use this to make a registry:

```
const registry = new Registry({
    A: {
        ctor: () => A
    },
    B: {
        ctor: () => B
    },
})

let a = registry.get('A', true)
//  ^? let a: A<Registry<{ A: A<any>; B: B<any>; }>>
let b = registry.get('B', 50)
//  ^? let b: B<Registry<{ A: A<any>; B: B<any>; }>>
let c = a.registry.get('C', true) // error!
let d = b.registry.get('C', true) // error!
```

You see the behavior you want. The return type of `registry.get('A', true)` is `A<Registry<{A: A<any>, B: B<any>}>>`, which is all the information you need.  Those [`any`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any)s don't hurt anything because they will be replaced by `this` whenever you drill down into `get()`.

---

So, that works. It's not necessarily the *best* approach, or even a *good* approach, and there are other approaches mentioned in microsoft/TypeScript#1213 you might want to explore.  Until and unless we get true higher-kinded types in TypeScript, though, you'll have to either give up or work around it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAShYHsDOBLYCBOIAiEkGMMUx0MAeAFSggA9gIA7AEySgCEBDJCMjhkADRQ+IAHyioAXigBvAFBRFUfKQBcUABQBKKRI0MIAd00ISKBAyTq4iVKRAB5MxaS9+QkaJ2SJFLXIBfOWCUBnoMADMOfGgAYQAbLiQAGRQkYDIYajpGFlgIAHM04Cw3MQkZKCDQSCgAQTAweJBKISzaemZWOCL00s8JSQUlSoBtAGkoUKgAawgQBAioBKTU9MzRAF1VYaUlKg7c1hWkFOKy0QnNqAB+ZcTTtYyYS-Hr9QMANwgMXarRuYLJYnM7rF6bYL4B7dQrFUrtHJdWRQAHzdR9UIFbbsLg8EQefgSAIVP4YeDINCYFB4dRjSbTQGLWDYmwU+y4AhEEiYTJXInBPb4FwlACuKkwGjJvRKIFpKPpDFm8yZMBZ5LsmBweEIxFIvLeRJ08j2e2AAAs0gA6Mm2SlEPBSKBSuEgP5BP4FCAZSaHJEYhgFKAAMiVQNgog0gPU4yEn2sV1GAHJPonNlp1A0mi0YFchOa0iSTUp4l7lKRHfmkNb1XbqUhUSBNpbxRhtABuP57MnAEUYRUGYwtjSVDDqSuxoQMdSAqo6Lg47hlAliYSsTPNfWbPMWpCiDt7ILumrQVkarBOYDmSyZIQANUGsj+U6g-oKAj+cagt9J1kCwTkUJJAuPAwHehZKM6fSyrAT7oiUmIfuo35-EKliikOlQMBOTpVNYNb2BeV6uKBX5eI+RaKJW1bSlgjq-BRUBUYq0gMJ2ShUZ8jqfG6f6QtC9QbNknR5Jwi4kQARggCAlnwFTCI6ACMVRyKE4RRDE9yrOcLzInUGaCQEUAAPRGVAZAALTmVABgQEwjEIMITB2ZW9lQAgvZQAARIBpxQPExSef+PmsGwgm+iJuI3tZIoALbiT8cniY6ABMymqT86lxNCTyCZUbDqKFOmGSZZmWdZEC2a5HBOYxO6ue5GBecFfkBUFwpOrCUGOgO+Q0SAw5-Hp5EUS26jaLo9Ruu+ez5cNRajZo3gSGwU2BP4cglsA8nSJBMqWp6wAaImdSJnmGAihA-glVAAB6dybcI+k9C6ZCVENdQXG27AFZ9VTiBtpZJTtnV7QdR1sKdUAAKwAAxXaZt33YDP3PVBr31PpnhfbNoVY39ogA1t+COhw1EuvtXpHbEkOipdxmmT8GCYAAhITUB2dI4lk1BFOHYm1NnRdOglYzLNAA)

Comment: That's straight, clear and full of nice tips beyond the main question. Thanks again for your patience and the quality of your answer.